# Problem with Factory_girl, association and after_initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I have a Family class so defined:

```
class Family < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :initialize_family
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, 
       :presence => true

  validates :name,   
       :presence => true,          
       :length => { :maximum => 30 },
       :format => { :with => /\A[a-zA-Z0-9\-_\s\']+\z/i}

  def initialize_family
    if self.name.blank? && self.user
        self.name = "#{self.user.profile_full_name}'s Family"
    end
  end
end
```

In my factories.rb I have:

```
Factory.define :family do |f|
   f.association :user, :factory => :user
end
```

In my family_spec.rb I have

```
let(:family) { Factory(:family) }
```

But this fails with:

```
1) Family is valid with valid attributes
     Failure/Error: let(:family) { Factory(:family) }
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Name can't be blank, Name is invalid, Languages can't be blank, Languages is too short (minimum is 1 characters)
     # ./spec/models/family_spec.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/family_spec.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Using the debugger I can see that when after_initialize is called self.user is nil. Why is this happening? 
If I call the family with create or new everything works fine.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is the answer I got from Joe Ferris:

factory_girl doesn't pass arguments to the constructor. It uses #user= on
your model, and instantiates it without any arguments.

and this one from Ben Hughes:

To elaborate on what Joe is saying, after_initialize methods are called
immediately upon object initialization, and that time indeed user has not
been set.

So for example while this will work:

```
family = Family.create!(:user => @user) # or @user.families.create ...
```

This will not (which is what factory_girl is doing under the hood):

```
family = Family.new
family.user = @user
family.save!
```

Just in general you want to be real careful using after_initialize, as
remember this is called on *every object initialization*. A Family.all call
on 1,000 objects will cause that to get called 1,000 times.

Sounds like in this instance you might be better of using a
before_validation instead of after_initialize.

The following syntax also works for testing in rspec:

```
let (:family) { Family.create(:user => @user) }
```

Comment: Ok, that's really helped. But it's confused :*(
Sorry for bad English

Comment: Did they gain any benefits by not instantiating new objects with their arguments? As @GuiGS says below, one can use `initialize_with` so it's certainly not a design limitation of factory_girl. I wonder why `initialize_with`'s behaviour isn't the default?

Answer (score 19):

Since `after_initialize` is triggered after new objects are instantiated and factory_girl builds instances by calling `new` without any arguments by default, you must use [`initialize_with`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/v4.5.0/GETTING_STARTED.md#custom-construction) to overwrite the default build.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :family do
    initialize_with { new(user: build(:user)) }
  end
end
```

Comment: While Matteo answer answers why, this is the actual the how to.

Comment: It can also be called like this `initialize_with { new(attributes) }`

Comment: That really helped! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's because the association is lazy, thus in the "after_initialize" there's no user yet.

http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/factory_girl/v1.3.3/file/README.rdoc

Perhaps you can directly call one factory from another, but I didn't try this, e.g.

```
f.user Factory(:user)
```