# create migrations for dependent tables in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my rails application I am having users module which is dependent on roles model.Both are integrated via user_role_assignment model.i.e An user has many roles associated via the user roles assignment.

I am in need to generate a migration to create some default users.
The problem I a facing is if I try to create a user via console,I get an error saying "roles can't be blank.

```
u=User.create(:name => "ramyameena", :email => "ramyameena@sandvine.com",:password=>"sandvine",:roles=>{:id=>2,:name=>"Tester"})
=> #<**User id: nil**, name: "ramyameena", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, email: "ramyameena@sandvine.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$qIfRLKZlxviag9E0Gzvp8e3VKkOCaXraP7PnJC6vGMN....", reset_password_token: nil, remember_token: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil>

irb(main):012:0> u.errors.inspect
=> "#<OrderedHash **{:roles=>[\"can't be blank\"]**}>"
```

My users model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
validates :roles, :presence => true
has_many :user_role_assignments
has_many :roles, :through => :user_role_assignments
has_many :tester_release_assignments
has_many :releases, :through => :tester_release_assignments
has_many :releases
has_many :ic_runs
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_role_assignments
attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :role_ids
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916162/problem-with-factory-girl-association-and-after-initialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_roles_assignments` but on create you're passing in *roles*, not user_roles_assignments. I'd check that you aren't missing `accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles` or a helper method of some sort...

Alternatively, you'll need to do the roles separately. eg

```
u = User.new(:name => "ramyameena", :email => "ramyameena@sandvine.com",:password=>"sandvine")
u.roles.build(:id=>2,:name=>"Tester")
u.save
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Taryn for taking pains to answer me first. Could please help with the console command to insert a user into the table . I tried giving value for the roles via u=User.create(:name => "ramyameena", :email => "ramyameena@sandvine.com",:password=>"sandvine",:roles=>{:id=>2,:name=>"Tester"}) .But it doesn't work.

Comment: That's because you have nothing defined in user that allows you to pass in any attributes for `:roles`. I don't know how your roles are setup. but you'll either need `accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles` or you'll need to do the roles separately. (see edit in answer above)

Comment: hi Taryn,I have 3 tables basically, user,roles,user_role_assignment.My roles table is already populated.I need to create an user and associate a role with the user by having an entry in user_role_assignment which has the user_id and role_id

Comment: On giving the above 2 commands mentioned by u I am getting an error saying "ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved: You cannot call create unless the parent is saved"

Comment: Ok... so save the parent first :) Actually - it's probably happening because it needs roles to save. I'll alter the example

Comment: Ok, I've edited the example to not save before a role exists. Give that a whirl.

Comment: Thanks a ton Taryn.That helped .Thanks a million